# How does APN figures out the location of device to which a Push Notification is to be sent

Tags: apple-push-notifications

I know that APN has a device token on the basis of which it identifies the device to which a notification is to be pushed.

I want know, how exactly it is able to deliver the notification using this Device token ? 
What happens in the background ?

How does it coordinate with the mobile service provider to deliver the notification ?

Answer (score 2):

Basically, the device id is encrypted within the device token, which enables the APN service to identify the device that needs to receive the notification. The notification is delivered over the data connection (either mobile data connection or WiFi).

Here are some relevant quotes from the [Push Notifications Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH1-SW1) :

> Apple Push Notification service (APNs) propagates push notifications
>   to devices having applications registered to receive those
>   notifications.  Each device establishes an accredited and encrypted IP
>   connection with the service and receives notifications over this
>   persistent connection.
>
> In APNs, assurance of accurate message routing—or token trust—is made
>   possible through the device token. A device token is an opaque
>   identifier of a device that APNs gives to the device when it first
>   connects with it.
>
> Applications must register to receive push notifications; it typically
>   does this right after it is installed on a device. (This procedure is
>   described in “Scheduling, Registering, and Handling Notifications.”)
>   The system receives the registration request from the application,
>   connects with APNs, and forwards the request. APNs generates a device
>   token using information contained in the unique device certificate.
>   The device token contains an identifier of the device. It then
>   encrypts the device token with a token key and returns it to the
>   device.
>
> Every notification that a provider sends to APNs for delivery to a
>   device must be accompanied by the device token it obtained from an
>   application on that device. APNs decrypts the token using the token
>   key, thereby ensuring that the notification is valid. It then uses the
>   device ID contained in the device token to determine the destination
>   device for the notification.

Comment: Here's  an updated source: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/APNSOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH8-SW1